# Express not listening on localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, npm

So, we've built a basic [express node website](https://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express)

[image: express -c stylus express_example]

Trying to run the app with `DEBUG=express_example:* npm start`

[image: DEBUG=express_example:* npm start]

With `node DEBUG=express_example:* npm start`

Also, tried inside `node` runtime:

[image: DEBUG=express_example:* npm start inside node]

http://localhost:3000/ is not connecting

[image]

**Where are we wrong?**

Comment: Can you show us some of your launch script ?

Comment: @Pogrindis What is the meaning of launch script

Comment: It's most likely the `app.js` file, need to see how express is being served and initialized.

Comment: I see, just to test https://github.com/shapeshed/express_example/blob/master/bin/www#L15 change this port var to = `3000;` only.. and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a variable called `DEBUG` with set command.
There is not command like `DEBUG`, it is a name of variable, so please try to run your server with set (to create variable):

`set DEBUG=express_example:* & npm start`

Comment: Good spot actually

Comment: @KrzysztofBargieł Yes, it worked!!! Thanks brotha! Can you educate me on what made you decide that `DEBUG` is not a command and it needs to be **set**.

Comment: @student 
It is a basic knowledge. You can check this out : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754250(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DEBUG='express_example:*' npm start
```

Your environment variable was not getting set properly. Note that you can have many different environment variables this way

```
TEST=foo DEBUG='bar' npm start
```